# Implement Pagination with LINQ (C#)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I am a newbie with Database Applications.

I would like to implement pagination with lower memory footprint. The application is connected to MS SQL Server 2008 R2 DB.

The table I have consists of thousands of records and the application can query the records with given criteria.

The current implementation using LINQ-SQL for querying and the whole data will be returned the application. If the query returns too much of results, this could exhaust the process memory. Hence I would like to implement this as pages.

I came across some stored procedures across the web which can paginate the data.

I am not sure if the standard pagination can help me to meet the following requirements

- Reduce the memory footprint, returns only required results on demand.
- Retain the query status. The same records can be updated while user seeing the the data in the view. So the state and the number of results has to be maintained regardless of the current state of table but regarding to the last query.
- If LINQ is used to implement the pagination, will this load the process to store the entire results?

Comment: hi check my answer i already wrote aritcle on that and won the price for the same...

Answer (score 5):

Pagination is not a problem using Linq you can do pagination using `Take()` and `Skip()`

```
var page = list.Skip((pageNo - 1) * pageSize)
               .Take(pageSize)
```

Comment: Could you please comment on retaining the state of the results?

Comment: There are number of ways of doing it, one way is to have cache at front end and show the fetched records on the UI.

Comment: Yeah but sometimes this could exhaust the process memory! Probably have to work with files.

Answer (score 3):

Grid view control has the following features:

- Linq 2 SQL support
- Custom paging using Linq 2 SQL
- Display sorting direction
- Dropdown in the pager to adjust the number of records in a page

[**LINQ TO SQL GridView (Enhanced Gridview)**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93253/LINQ-TO-SQL-GridView-Enhanced-Gridview)